# How to change DateField format representation

Tags: python, django

i do have a field in model DateField 
so when i render it on webpage it shows

```
12-30-2012
```

and i need

```
30.12.2012
```

i tried to use inside template

```
{{ item.pub_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") }}
```

but i recieve and error of parsing. in console it works fine.
 then i tried to make a new method in model

```
get_pub_date(self):
    self.pub_date.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
```

and i recieve same error parsing of template when i call this method in tempalte

Comment: solved from here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 1):

Use [date template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date):

```
{{ item.pub_date|date:"d.m.Y" }}
```

Also note:

> When used without a format string:

```
{{ value|date }}
```

> ...the formatting string defined in the DATE_FORMAT setting will be used, without applying any localization.

Comment: Good job ! please [close the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that other helpers that read the list of questions, spending time to find someone to help, can avoid this question :)